# PHP: $_SESSION variables not passing to the next webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I am having trouble trying to pass my username variable from a login page to the next 'welcome' page. I am hosting the web pages using my **university's** server and therefore access my web files within a public_html folder.

When testing on the login.php page I am able to print the username that is held in the session however when I try the same in the member's page it does not print the username held in the session array? I have checked all other posts however no solution seems to work.

**Login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('connect.php');
$userName=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$userName' AND password='$password'") or die ('Query is invalid: ' . mysql_error());;
$count =  mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{
$_SESSION['username']=$userName;
header("Location: memberPage.php");
} else {
echo "Incorrect username or password";
}
?>
```

**memberLogin.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('connection.php');

$_SESSION['username'] = $userName;
echo $userName;

//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
//while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
//    echo $row['username'];
//}
?> 

<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<div id = main-nav>
<a href="http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~rxp00u/logout.php" >Logout</a> 
</div>
</html>
```

P.S. I realise my code is not very secure and I will be working on this after getting the basic framework of the website working!

EDIT: Error reporting on login.php shows the following error:
"Warning: Unknown: open(/var/lib/php5/sess_d760m9ebgose4liptp6jbgbc17nqjgg4, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php5) in Unknown on line 0"

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('connection.php');

$_SESSION['username'] = $userName;
echo $userName;
```

$userName is not set. If you had errors on you'd have seen that. Did you mean

```
$userName = $_SESSION['username'];
echo $userName;
```

?

Comment: thanks, i tried this however still no output of the username that is logged in

Comment: just try replacing `header("Location: memberPage.php");` with a meta refresh `echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=memberPage.php">';` - it's a cookie thing

Comment: thanks, that redirected me back to memberPage but nothing still shows on the memberPage.php

Comment: Hi, after turning errors on I have seen that I have errors when writing my sessions to the file. I am on my university's server so have the web files within a public_html folder so am not sure where the php files would be held? Here is the error that was outputted in my login.php file: "Warning: Unknown: open(/var/lib/php5/sess_d760m9ebgose4liptp6jbgbc17nqjgg4, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php5) in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: ok for now make your own session dir and use it http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Comment: i changed the session change path and the error is the same but ends with: "Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (H:\public_html) in Unknown on line 0 "

Comment: H:\public_html probably isn't a path judging by the path given in that warning. `echo getcwd()` you're looking to be using a path like /var/www/something/httpdocs/

Comment: Works great!! Thank you! I used echo getcwd(); to find my path that I had needed and passed that to session_save_path('the_actual_path'); and it now prints the username onto the next page. Thanks!

Comment: ok. just one thing - create a dir sessions rather than using the one you're in.

Comment: so just a folder within that path called sessions would suffice?

Answer (score 1):

on **memberLogin.php** you are setting:

`$_SESSION['username'] = $userName;`

where `$userName` is undefined. it appears that if you can successfully assign `$userName` to a `$_SESSION` variable on **Login.php**, you no longer need to set the variable. It will be accessible once you call `session_start();`.

Comment: if i do not need to set the variable again how would i access $userName in memberPage.php?

Comment: `$userName = $_SESSION['username'];`

Answer (score 0):

In memberLogin, it should be:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Assignment is left associative, meaning the value on the right of the `=` is assigned to the variable on the left of the `=`.  Your current setup has you overwriting your session value with null.

Comment: thanks i tried this but no luck with any output of the session's username

Comment: Do some basic debugging to narrow the problem: Do you have error reporting turned on?  Have you tried running your query in phpMyAdmin?  Can you var_dump `$username` in login.php?  Can you var_dump `$_SESSION['username']` after the assignment in login.php?

Comment: I turned on error reporting and found errors when trying to write session data. I am currently on my university's machine and so accessing my web files would be held in my public_html folder. The error was as follows: "Warning: Unknown: open(/var/lib/php5/sess_d760m9ebgose4liptp6jbgbc17nqjgg4, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php5) in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: Ah, well there's your problem.  Edit your question with those details.  Be sure to mention you're on a university server.  That's pertinent.